# Is there a classifying space for transitive Lie algebroids? If so, what is it?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-algebras, classifying-spaces, lie-groupoids, lie-algebroids

Let $M$ be a manifold. The data of a Lie groupoid over $M$ is equivalent to the data of a singular foliation $M=\sqcup\mathcal{F}_i$ and, for each $i$, a map (mod homotopy) $f_i:F_i\to BG_i$ (where $G_i$ is a Lie group). In particular, given any Lie group $G$, there is a universal transitive Lie groupoid with isotropy $G$; call it $U\xrightarrow{s\times t}BG$. We can now differentiate this to get a Lie algebroid $L(U)\xrightarrow{\rho} T(BG)\to BG$, which is the universal *integrable* transitive Lie algebroid with isotropy $\mathfrak{g}=L(G)$. I'm interested in removing the integrability assumption.

To be precise, I would like the following for each Lie group $G$ (equivalently each Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$):

1. A manifold $B\mathfrak{g}$
2. A Lie algebroid $\mathfrak{u}\xrightarrow{\rho}T(B\mathfrak{g})\to B\mathfrak{g}$, such that
3. For any transitive Lie algebroid $A$ of isotropy $\mathfrak{g}$ over $M$, there is a map $f:M\to B\mathfrak{g}$ unique up to homotopy such that $A\cong f^*\mathfrak{u}$ (where the pullback is the one defined via the Chevalley-Eilenberg algebra, equivalently by choosing a homotopy class which is transverse to the anchor if possible).

Some notes about this:

- I am given to understand that arbitrary Lie algebroids can be integrated to Lie $2$-groupoids, but I do not know if transitive Lie $2$-groupoids can be classified as above. If I can find a classifying stack or $\infty$-stack rather than a classifying space, I'll still be happy (in fact, I rather expect something like this).
- I am also interested in the complex and algebraic cases of this; in fact, the origin of this problem was classifying formal groupoids in characteristic zero.

Comment: A Lie groupoid determines the singular foliation on $M$ and the classifying maps $f_i$, but this data does not determine the Lie groupoid. 
For example, a vector bundle can be seen as a Lie groupoid, (a bundle of abelian groups). The leaves $F_i$ are the points of $M$, and thus contractible.
So the homotopy classes $f_i$ are the same for different vector bundles, i.e., for different groupoids. That data determines the foliation and s-fibres, but ignores how the s-fibres fit together geometrically. It is not a problem in the transitive case

Comment: Yes, I realized that after writing the question. I suppose that it's just a question of splitting the Atiyah sequence, at least for the algebroid version.